# Tweaking Chrome style with Ubuntu theme

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, themes, chromium

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with ARC theme. In the GTK2 file I found:

```
# Chrome/Chromium
widget_class "*Chrom*Button*"                                       style "button"
widget_class "*<GtkCustomMenu>*<GtkCustomMenuItem>*"                style "chrome_menu_item"

# Chromium
style "chrome_menu_item" { bg[SELECTED] = @selected_bg_color }
```

and I can change chrome selected Menu BG color there. I want to change these colors:

[image: chrome]

[image: chrome]

- Bookmark panel background color
- Menu border color
- Menu item hover text color
- Address bar suggestion selected color and background color

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution for this? I am also interested for the address bar suggestions selection color

Comment: @Adrian Sadly no. Recently I saw Chrome on Windows and it looks so nice. It even don't get some colors from OS. for example hovering menu background color is something like `white smoke`. On Linux I changed that with `Theme Configuration` but other colors can't change from there.

Comment: I ended up setting GTK theme on Chrome and I modified the colors from the themes folder

Comment: @Adrian If you want to change it with theme, you can use https://www.themebeta.com/chrome-theme-creator-online.html . Themes slowing down chrome effects for me and It can't modified all colors such as menu borders.